Interchanging the order of integration for the convolution covariance property of Fourier transform
I'm attempting to derive the convolution covariance of a Fourier transform equation:
$$\mathcal{F}(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{a}^{b} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(u) y\left( {\tau} - u\right) \, du \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^*(v) y^*\left({\tau} - v\right) \, dv \right) e^{-j\omega \tau} \, d\tau $$
Can I interchange the order of integration in making this equation?
$$\mathcal{F}(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(u) x^*(v) \left( \int_{a}^{b} y\left({\tau} - u\right) y^*\left({\tau} - v\right) e^{-j\omega \tau} \, d\tau \right) du \, dv $$
I cautioned myself with the involved variable when interchanging but I may have missed something.

In general, the interchange is not permissible.  But if the conditions of Fubini's theorem (or Fubin-Tonelli) are satisfied, then the interchange is valid.
